# getting error to display all record in php json

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to display all records using jason in php.
but display all filed with null value.
I'm using postman for testing purpose.
[image]

I don't know what is the problem with that code. I getting null value only.

**here is my code :**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$checkFields = "";
$REQUEST = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if ($REQUEST == "POST")
{
    include "DB/db.php";        

    $userlist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reg_services"); 
    if(mysql_num_rows($userlist) > 0)
    {
        $p = 0;
        $ph = array();
        while($userlistdata = mysql_fetch_row($userlist)) 
        {
            $ph[$p]["UserId"] = $userlistdata['id'];
            $ph[$p]["FirstName"] = $userlistdata['fname'];            
            $ph[$p]["LastName"] = $userlistdata['lname'];
            $ph[$p]["Email"] = $userlistdata['email'];
            $ph[$p]["Mobile"] = $userlistdata['mobile'];    
            $ph[$p]["Password"] = $userlistdata['password']; 
            $p++;
        }
        $json = array("success" => 1, "All_User_List" => $ph);
        $jsonarray = json_encode($json);
    } 
}
else
{
    $json = array("success" => 0, "message" => "Invalid Request Type(Use POST Method)");
    $jsonarray = json_encode($json);    
}

echo $jsonarray;
?>
```

please help me if you are know what is the error in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace this code with old one

```
$p = 0;
        $ph = array();
        while($userlistdata = mysql_fetch_array($userlist)) 
        {
            $ph[$p] = array();
            $ph[$p]["UserId"] = $userlistdata['id'];
            $ph[$p]["FirstName"] = $userlistdata['fname'];            
            $ph[$p]["LastName"] = $userlistdata['lname'];
            $ph[$p]["Email"] = $userlistdata['email'];
            $ph[$p]["Mobile"] = $userlistdata['mobile'];    
            $ph[$p]["Password"] = $userlistdata['password']; 
            $p++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell PHP about arrays

```
    while($userlistdata = mysql_fetch_row($userlist)) 
    {
        $ph[$p] = array(); // let PHP know it is an array
        $ph[$p]["UserId"] = $userlistdata['id'];
        $ph[$p]["FirstName"] = $userlistdata['fname'];            
        $ph[$p]["LastName"] = $userlistdata['lname'];
        $ph[$p]["Email"] = $userlistdata['email'];
        $ph[$p]["Mobile"] = $userlistdata['mobile'];    
        $ph[$p]["Password"] = $userlistdata['password']; 
        $p++;
    }
```

Comment: `while($userlistdata = mysql_fetch_array($userlist)) `
like that right?

Comment: No, you defined `$ph` as array, not `$ph[$p]`. Did you try it?

Comment: Sorry typo, adjusted now

Comment: sorry... Means?

Answer (score 0):

just replace this while loop condition with olde one.

```
while($userlistdata = mysql_fetch_array($userlist))
```

now it's work